# Questions on APIs

Tags: couchbase

I came up with more questions ! YAY! (sorry)

1. what does "libcouchbase_set_cookie" Api do?

I can see that it sets cookie, but all of the APIs of libcouchbase has "cookie" as parameter that we can put it in. Why is there another API doing this?

Explanation of this "cookie" thing will be very helpful thank you.

1. IO_opt ... seems like setting IO option api to me... I will look in the source folder to check but any explanation on this will be helpful aswell since I couldn't get any info on the couchbase website

Comment: will post this in forum of couchbase.com as well under SDKs

Comment: In memcached the cookie is the connection object. I haven't looked at the libcouchbase api though.

Comment: hmm can you check on this please? this is really confusing since all apis like get, store, remove, etc. all has "cookie" parameter as well. I really wanna check the difference of these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In libcouchbase there are two forms of cookies, one is the 'user context' for the operation, (and gets passed to you in the callback) and one is the 'user context' for the actual libcouchbase_t handle. (Not to confuse, but there is yet a third cookie associated specifically with the iops structure :) ).

the 'cookie' in libcouchbase is similar to this idiom you'd find:

```
struct frobnicate_st {
/* private library stuff */
...
/* store anything you like here */
void *user_data;
};
```

in some other libraries.

Because the context and the lifetime of a single operation can span multiple callbacks, and because you will typically need to store the result of the operation (status code, and actual value) somewhere, the cookie argument is specifically helpful (if not downright necessary)

You can poke around the libcouchbase test suite and see how it is used there in simple contexts.

Comment: Thanks that was the difference between those two cookies ... understood :D

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is used to allow you to associate context with an operation. It is not required should be set to NULL if not used. Below is the documentation for the cookie from the libcouchbase project.

```
<argument id="cookie" type="const void*">
  <m_title>Client cookie</m_title>
  <description>
    This is a cookie the client may attach to all requests that will be
    included in all callbacks. It is not required and may be NULL if
    you have no need for it.
  </description>
  <langtype id="c" type="const void*"/>
</argument>
```

Comment: I tested this and working well. however my other question is this "libcouchbase_set_cookie" API... I don't see why this is actually required. Since other APIs actually have their own parameter of cookie. What is the difference between these two?